# uploading file to intranet site using batch file

Tags: batch-file, sharepoint, file-upload, cmd, intranet

so right now I have 2 files. A batch file that looks like this:

```
open http://kmsbs/Shared%20Documents/
username
password
option confirm off
cd C:\Users\a\Desktop\
put "C:\Users\a\Desktop\Contract.pdf"
quit
```

and a cmd file that looks like this:

```
ftp -s:c:\Users\a\Desktop\upload.bat
pause
```

My goal here is to upload a file to my intranet site using the batch file so i can then schedule the task manager to automatically run this file every day. When i run the cmd file, it says unknown host http://kmsbs/Shared%20Documents/
I was wondering if anyone knows why I'm getting this error. Thanks.

Comment: Not to sound like a smartass, but you generally get that error when the  host doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

Only in case the remote host `kmsbs` has **FTP**-server software configured and running and accept connections from the intranet you can actually use FTP.

The `open` command expects just a server name, so remove `http://` and `/Shared%20Documents/` and change the remote directory normally: `cd` for remote server, `lcd` for the local server. Also don't use full paths in `put`: you already have changed the directory locally.

```
open kmsbs
username
password
option confirm off
cd /Shared%20Documents/
lcd C:\Users\a\Desktop
put Contract.pdf
quit
```

Comment: thank you very muc for your help, so it seems like the open kmsbs works but once i get to the username part i get "invalid command" as a response, do you know why that might be?

Comment: Maybe your ftp server doesn't require you to enter the credentials. Read the messages: if the user name is required a corresponding prompt will be displayed. Anyway, it's not related to programming so you'd better ask someone in your organization.

Comment: ok, so when i remove the username and password it gets to "option confirm off" and says "Invalid command." do you know why that doesnt work? thanks again

Comment: do the obvious thing: remove that line and use `-i` command line switch: `ftp -i -s:...........`